# Use a list to define SELECT columns in a query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a need to query from a parquet file where the column names are completely inconsistent. In order to remedy this issue and insure that my model gets exactly the data it expects I need to 'prefetch' the columns list then apply some regex patterns to qualify which columns I need to retrieve. In pseudocode:

```
PrefetchList = sqlContext.read.parquet(my_parquet_file).schema.fields
# Insert variable statements to check/qualify the columns against rules here
dfQualified = SELECT [PrefetchList] from parquet;
```

I've searched around to see if this is achievable but not had any success. If this is syntactically correct (or close) or if someone has other suggestions I am open to it.

Thanks

Comment: I see the tags pyspark and I am assuming you are using Python buy If you are fine with using scala , case class can solve your problem effectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the `schema` method but you can also use the `.columns` method.
Notice that the select method in spark is a little odd, it's defined as `def
select(col: String, cols: String*)` so you can't pass back to it `select(fields:_*)`, and you'd have to use `df.select(fields.head, fields.tail:_*)` which is kind of ugly, but luckily there's `selectExpr(exprs: String*)` as an alternative. So this below will work. It takes only columns that begin with 'user'

```
fields = df.columns.filter(_.matches("^user.+")) // BYO regexp
df.selectExpr(fields:_*)
```

This of course assumes that `df` contains your dataframe, loaded with  `sqlContext.read.parquet()`.